# Arithmetic operations on float values return unexpected answer

Tags: java

If i print the value of x for :

```
int a=1;
int b=6;
float x=(a/b);
```

The output is 0.0

But if i change the third line to 
    float x = (float)a/(float)b;

The output is 0.1666667(which it should be)

Why the difference?

Comment: Search for "Integer Division"...

Comment: Many people do integer division in primary school and forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a/b` is calculated as the division of two integers and therefore its result is an integer, and so everything beyond the decimal floating point is truncated and you end up with `0.0`.

For example: if you had:

```
int a = 6;
int b = 4;
float x =(a/b);
```

You would get that `x = 1.0` because the result of the calculation is truncated, and then when you assign it to a float, the integer result value `1` gets cast to a float, i.e. `1.0`.

When you calculate `(float)a/(float)b`, you're calculating the division of two `float` variables and the result is `float` (the same would happen if only one of the variables / values was `float` and the other one was `integer`).

Answer (score 1):

That is because both of the variables are of type `int` and hence the division returns an `int`.

You'll have to cast at least one of them to `float` in order to force the division to return the result in `float`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 6;
    float x = ((float)a/b);
    System.out.println("Result: " + x);
}
```

Output:

```
Result: 0.16666667
```

**Note:** In the above example, I have casted `a` to `float`. You can also cast `b` to `float` instead of `a` as follows:

```
float x = (a/(float)b);
```